# Oracle Forms- 'FND_MESSAGE' issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

I have created one POPUP in Oracle Forms  (Custom PLL - Oracle EBS R12)

```css
fnd_message.set_name ('XX', 'CASCADE_SHIPPING_METHOD');
         --    fnd_message.show;
         n_button_selection :=
            fnd_message.question ('Yes',
                                  'No',
                                  '',
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  3);
 
 
IF n_button_selection = 1
         THEN
             Procedure1();
         ELSIF n_button_selection = 2
         THEN
             Procedure2();
         ELSE
            NULL;
         END IF;
```

This code is working fine But, If the User CLOSE the form(by clicking the 'X' mark), then **ELSIF** condition is executed and calling the procedure2. I expect the control goes to **ELSE** and do nothing.
Kindly help.

I modified the code as

```js
 fnd_message.set_name ('XX', 'CASCADE_SHIPPING_METHOD');
      
         n_button_selection :=
            fnd_message.question ('Yes',
                                  'No',
                                  'Cancel',
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  3);

         --If user select "Yes" option to cascade, then enter inside if and call the proc to cascade

         IF n_button_selection = 1
         THEN
          MESSAGE('Pressed Yes-For Lines Cascading');
          shipping_method (l_header_id,
                            ship_method,
                           'Lines');
         ELSIF n_button_selection = 2
         THEN
         MESSAGE('Pressed No-For Header Cascading');
            shipping_method (l_header_id,
                              ship_method,
                               'Header');
         ELSE
          MESSAGE('Inside ELSE Condition');
            NULL;
         END IF;
```

but still If I close the form the control Goes to **Button Selection 2** that is ELSIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fnd_message.set_name ('XX', 'CASCADE_SHIPPING_METHOD');
         --    fnd_message.show;
         n_button_selection :=
            fnd_message.question ('Yes',
                                  'No',
                                  'Cancle',
                                  1,
                                  3);


IF n_button_selection = 1
         THEN
             Procedure1();
         ELSIF n_button_selection = 2
         THEN
             Procedure2();
         ELSE
            NULL;
         END IF;
```

Comment: Hi Vinish, Thank you for your response, will try this and let you know if it works .. again many thanks for your suggesytion.

Comment: Please see my update .. actually it went to ELSIF again. I changed the IF condition to CASE . still if we click on X its going to CASE 2

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer again, try that one. Actually after Cancle parameter ,1 is for default ok button and 3 is for default cancle button, no need of another parameter as it is for icon.